# Why is 'bpy.context.active_object.pose' of type 'NoneType'?

Tags: python, scripting, documentation

It might be my inexperience of reading too much technical documentation or little experience in python, but, I'm having a bit of trouble reading the documentation. The command that triggered this confusion is:

```
bpy.context.active_object.pose
```

What is the `Type` of the options in the `bpy` docs, like in here:

[image]

Up until now I assumed that it was the type of the associated variable accessed from the module or the type inherited from, but, for this particular case, I'm a bit confused, from the interactive console:

```
>>> type(bpy.context.active_object.pose)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

but, the documentation gives it's type as Pose, which [in itself is a class](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Pose.html#bpy.types.Pose). Please explain what is this?

Comment: *In itself is a class* > None is a data type of its own (NoneType which is also a class) https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_none.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the object currently active or selected in the current context and defined in `bpy.context.active_object` does not have any pose data. It may not be applicable and thus [`NoneType`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21095731/7650260) gets returned by `bpy.context.active_object.pose`.

> **NoneType** is the type for the [None](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_none.asp) object, which is an object that
> indicates no value. None is the return value of functions that "don't
> return anything". It is also a common default return value for
> functions that search for something and may or may not find it.

If the selected object or current `active_object` was the default cube, `pose` would be *NoneType* because pose data is not applicable to the default cube. An armature, on the other hand, has pose data and if the `active_object` was indeed an armature then `bpy.context.active_object.pose` would return the [`Pose`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Pose.html) object.

Answer (score 1):

This is because, the object you have active in the current context, which is typically the 3D viewport , is not an armature. If it were an armature, then the type would be as stated in the documentation.